# Blender GUI Glitch with flashed Mac Pro

Tags: interface

I just installed Blender on my flashed Mac Pro 4,1 and the GUI is totally messed up. I'm not sure what to do. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What version of macOS / OSX are you using?

Comment: OSX 10.13.6 is the latest OS version I can use without a special hack.

Comment: I just looked through the requirements, and it says the minimum req for the GPU is 1G. I have three 512MB cards. Is that what could be causing it?

Comment: Please check what graphics cards you have. Are they ATI Radeon HD 2600XT, ATI Radeon HD5770 and ATI Radeon HD 5870?

Comment: I ended up finding out that I did *not* have a Metal2 compatible card. I upgraded to an RX580 and all is well! :)

Comment: Blender currently doesn't use Metal, but 2.8x has higher minimum requirements for the hardware, compared to 2.79b.